# Program works with all inputs except for one (Prime number checker)

Tags: c#, primes

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to learn new concepts so I made a prime number checker. It's probably not as efficient as it could be but I'm happy it works. However, whenever I input the number 4 it doesn't work. On all the other numbers it does but on 4 it doesn't. Here's my code:

```
            float prime = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
            float divisor = prime - 1;
            float checker = prime / divisor;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("checker = " + checker);
                checker = prime / divisor;
                --divisor;
            } while (checker % 1 != 0 && divisor >= 0);

            if (divisor < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is a prime number.", prime);
            }
            if (checker % 1 == 0 && divisor > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a prime number.", prime);
            }
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` can almost always be fixed with a little debugging

Comment: So it thinks 4 is a prime number?

Comment: No, it just doesn't say anything and then the program ends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Logic is buggy:

```
checker = prime / divisor;
```

checker = 4 / 2 => 2

```
while (checker % 1 != 0 && divisor >= 0)
```

2%1 = 0 -- Which exits the loop
You also have 2 If conditions (why not if & else). Second If condition does not match with the Loop ending condition.

This is my logic:

```
float input = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
float factor1 = 2;
float factor2 = 0;
bool isPrime = true;

for(; factor1 < input; factor1++)
{
    factor2 = input / (float)factor1;

    if((int)factor2 == factor2)
    {
        isPrime = false;                    
        break;
    }
}

if(isPrime)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is prime.");
}
else
{                
    Console.WriteLine($"{input} is not prime. {factor1} * {factor2} = {input}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your `if` statement conditions are met for 4. Change your second `if` statement to an `else` so that if your first statement is not executed the logic of the `else` statement always executes.

```
 if (divisor < 1)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is a prime number.", prime);
 }
 else
 {
     Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a prime number.", prime);
 }
```